# Почему Ajax постоянно выдает ошибку?

Tags: html, ajax

Постоянно выдает ошибку. Пробовал разные варианты ajax отправки - результат тот же. Дело даже не доходит до php обработчика..
Где ошибка?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    //E-mail Ajax Send
    $(".form-present").submit(function() { //Change
        var th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mail.php", //Change
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            alert("Thank you!");
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Done Functions
                th.trigger("reset");
            }, 1000);
        });
        alert("Ошибка");
        return false;
    });

});
```

```html
<form class="form-present">

                    <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="Site Name">
                    <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="blabla@gmail.com">
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Form Subject">
                    <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->

                    <input class="input" value="" type="text" required name="name_present" placeholder="Введите имя">
                    <input class="input"  value="" type="tel" required name="tel_present" placeholder="Введите телефон">
                <button class="button_form button-present" type="submit">Получить подарок</button>
                </form>
```

Видимо он постоянно возвращает return false;
Консоль пустая, вообще не могу понять, что не так..

Обработчик

```js
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

 $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
 $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
 $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);

 foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
  if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
   $message .= "
   " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
    <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
    <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
   </tr>
   ";
  }
 }
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

 $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
 $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
 $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);

 foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
  if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
   $message .= "
   " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
    <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
    <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
   </tr>
   ";
  }
 }
}

$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

function adopt($text) {
 return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
```

Сделал изменения, теперь ошибка вот.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что вы делаете асинхронный запрос, а алерт с false возвращаются еще до того как он успевает отработать. Добавьте .fail(function(){})  и поместите туда как раз ваш алерт с false

Comment: Изменил Код теперь выглядит вот так.https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKyQqy Вот скрин ошибки https://ibb.co/hdZqNy

Comment: Сервер вам вернул 503, ищите ошибки теперь у себя в php файле